# How to unload tables from hana for every one minute?

Tags: database, hana

I have to unload all the tables from the SAP HANA database every one minute. So I need actually a cronjob which automatically unload all the tables in the database every one minute. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no specific feature that would allow you to do that. Usually manually loading/unloading of table columns is *not* required nor recommended.

For cases where a preferred unloading is required, the `UNLOAD PRIORITY` table attribute can be used.

Unloading all tables on a regular basis doesn't make much sense when using an in-memory database. What's the use case here?

Comment: Actually not unloading all the tables.Because when our team works with different tables at the moment all the tables get loaded and get OOM error. So to avoid that we are planning to create a cronjob which unloads the table which are loaded for every 1 minute

Comment: Sounds like the system is either too small for your data or the queries run by your team are consuming too much memory. Unloading tables is not the solution here. Finding the cause of the excessive memory usage and fixing it is. In case you deal with tables that have a huge amount of records, it may be beneficial to just partition those and access only a subset of the records.
Besides that, sizing the HANA instance according to your data volume is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your instance is too small or your dataset too big for that instance. If that's not the scenario, you could check dynamic data-tiering. It allows you to choose what to have in disk (cold storage) and what to keep in-memory (hot storage): https://www.sap.com/developer/groups/dt-get-started.html